# Do these count as repositories or something else?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository

a) A class that downloads data from a webservice.
b) a class that loads configuration data to be used by a service class.

And they're both read only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [DDD definition](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/123), a "**repository** is a mechanism for encapsulating storage, retrieval, and search behavior which emulates a collection of objects."

So, yes, you could certainly create/implement a repository for searching and retrieving both of those types of information.  It is less about the type of data you want to retrieve, and more about the ability to separate the dependencies between your domain and data mapping layers.

The repository will allow your client code to retrieve data using a more standard interface without the need to know implementation details of each data source.  Additionally, in your example, the repository could be useful to add (just for example) caching abilities and additional query capabilities that may not be part of the standard web service or configuration data interfaces.